# Unable to write with FileOutputStream in a /resources file in maven project

Tags: java, maven, io

In a maven project i have an `image.jpg` file under `/resources` folder[image]

When i try to retrieve the file using

```
private static File getImage(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = Db.class.getClassLoader();
    return new File(classLoader.getResource("image.jpg").getFile());
}
```

The file returns properly, but when i try to put this file into a FileOutputStream to write some new data it doesn't work

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getImage());
fos.write(blobImage.getBytes(1, (int)blobImage.length()));
fos.flush(); fos.close();
```

I have no errors, it's just unable to write anything new, but if I change the FileOutputStream to this

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\...src\\main\\resources\\image.jpg");
```

It works properly, the image get changed to whatever was in the `blobImage` file.

Comment: Always use `class.getResourcesAsStream("/image.jpg")` instead of file...and never use an absolute path in your code based on File object...

Comment: What will happen when your code is being executed from an unexploded WAR file?  The write will fail.  You generally should NEVER write into your application's resources.  Permanent state should go in a database, and temporary state should go in temporary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
private static File getImage(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = Db.class.getClassLoader();
    return new File(classLoader.getResource("image.jpg").getFile());
}
```

you retrieve the `image.jpg` located in the runtime classpath : `target/classes` not in `src/main/resouces`.

`src/main/resouces` is the resource path used during Maven builds, not at runtime.
After the `process-resources` Maven phase execution, files/folders located in `src/main/resources` are copied to `target/classes`.

So after your change, the image is actually changed but which one located in `target/classes`.

---

Note that resources packaged in jar/war are not designed to be changed. You will get locking and caching issues. If resources may be changed, these should be located outside the component : filesystem is a fair choice for images.

Comment: I understand, is there a way to override the `image.jpg` in the resources folder with java code without having to use an absolute path ?

Comment: In fact, resources packaged in jar/war are not designed to be changed. You will get locking and caching issues. If resources may be changed, these should be located outside the component.